# SAP HANA map labels to categories in calculation view

Tags: label, mapping, hana

I set up a calculation view in SAP HANA (mind you, I am a total newbie to it) and I want to use it to get some nice visualizations with LUMIRA. The categorical variables (I guess database calls it dimensions) of my data are numerically encoded. So e.g. in the 'sex' column '0' stands for male and '1' for female.

I want to display the label rather than the numerical value to get more comprehensive graph. Does anybody know how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Jonas,

You can either create a calculated column with an if clause to replace the value in HANA:
[image: Calculated Columns in Aggregation]

Or you can use "Create a Calculated Dimension" in Lumira too, if you right-click on the column with the gender, depending on where the last level of aggregation is happening (hopefully in HANA)

Cheers,

Lucia

Answer (score 1):

An additional option that what Lucia wrote is to use **lookup tables**.

The benefit here is that these tables (also referred to as dimension tables) can be **reused** and are resolved via joins at query runtime. In many scenarios, this can be beneficial for the query runtime, as filters can be efficiently applied on the "label" values, while this is not possible with arbitrary calculated columns.

The reusability aspect is should also not be underestimated. If you analyse a lot of similar data sets and want to have consistent labels for concepts reusing the dimension table can save a lot of typing effort in a calculated column.

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. As mentioned, I am new to working with HANA. Could you maybe go into more detail on the structure I need to set up?